# Debug 500 Internal error in Bottle Py template in Azure

Tags: python, azure, bottle, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Bottle Py application using use Visual Studio python tools, bottle py template and deployed it to azure. Deployment was successful and the Website is hosted.  But when calling a rest url I am receiving 500 Internal error.  how to debug this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've published to an Azure Web Site, then you can use the Azure Web Site Remote Debugging feature which was added to PTVS 2.1 Beta 2.  You'll be able to set breakpoints and debug your site running on Azure.  Documentation is here:
http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features%20Azure%20Remote%20Debugging